# .NET 8 Blazor Handling Data With Auto/Global Interactivity

Tags: asp.net, blazor, rendering, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have been familiarizing myself with the .NET 8 Blazor Web App structure, and am trying to understand and use the "Auto" interactive render mode, with the "Global" interactivity location. Upon creating a new solution, there are two projects: server and wasm. Using the auto/global interactivity settings, components appear to always be server rendered first, and then switch over to wasm rendered. I really like this concept, however I am having issues handling data throughout this process.

When attempting to query a database from a component on the **wasm project**, the component is initially server rendered and the query results are displayed on the wasm component. However, once the server connection closes and the component rerenders as wasm, the component cannot access the server database and the query results disappear. Similarily, when attempting to query the database from a component on the **server project**, the component is initially server rendered and the query results are displayed on the server component. But once the server connection closes and the component attempts to rerender as wasm, there is a "sorry, page not found" error instead.

I have seen many example videos where users highlight this auto render switching. However, they all setup their projects with the per page/component interactivity location, and manually set these pages to keep an active server connection. With this in mind, what's the point of the global interactivity location handler?

- As noted in my example, the solution discards my server components when rerendering as wasm. Why even use this "global" setting if the server side components are essentially unusable?
- If the point of this configuration is to globally auto switch from server to wasm on every component, why is there no built in way to handle the query results or similar data when rerendering as wasm?
- When querying a database, how should I appropriately retain this data when auto switching from server to wasm?

While I'm loving the concept of the global auto switch, I feel like I'm missing a key part of understanding how to correctly utilize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all about design and abstraction.

Consider your database example.

In your application, your component should be talking to a View Provider that uses a `IDataBroker` interface to get it's data.

In Server mode the DI `IDataBroker` connects to say EF.  In WASM mode the DI `IDataBroker` makes API calls to controllers on the Server.  The UI and Core domain code is the same.  It just interfaces through different implementations of the `IDataBroker` provided by DI.

You therefore need to design your data pipeline to run both:

1. directly through EF
2. via an API pipeline

i.e. Your requests, such as collection filtering and sorting, need to be serializable.

There's no silver bullet in Net8 that connects a `dbContext` call from a component to a database in WASM.  When your page component switches mode, it needs to switch `IDataBroker` implementation.

Here's a link to demo implementation of A SSR/CSR data pipeline based on the Weather page https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/An-Interactive-Data-Pipeline.md

Comment: Yes. But an alt is to always go through the API. Blazor server, even with SSR, can do that too.

Comment: @HH - Agreed. I my data pipelines the API Server pipeline is exactly the same pipeline as the Blazor Server, just with a different presentation layer - an API controller, rather than a View Presenter in Blazor Server.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis if I wanted to avoid having two service implementations and instead have the SSR (interactive and static) mode make API calls the same way as CSR mode, then how do you setup the httpclient factory on the server side project so that it uses the correct base URL, headers, and cookies as the client side?

Comment: Here's a link to a "work-in-progress" repository with a demo on how to build a  SSR/CSR data pipeline - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/An-Interactive-Data-Pipeline.md