# Blazor Server/Web Client / C# / First API call from client is returning a 302

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I am working on a Blazor application that is Server/WASM.

I'm in .NET 8 and trying the new **InteractiveAuto** functionality.

I have my login and authenication completed on the Blazor Server project.

I have a page that goes out to the database and pulls in my SeriLogs.

The very first call after logging in with using **InteractiveAuto** it calls my http client API call, but returns a 302 and tries to redirect to the account/login page.

If I go to another page, then back it works.

Here is the error I receive on the first call:

> Error
> '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

I assume the call fails on the redirect 302 and then fails on the response being JSON.

Seems like there is the 302 and it redirects, then gives a 200?

Here is my setup:

**WebClient Razor page:**

```
@page "/maintenance/seri-log"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using MyApp.Client.Services
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@using MyApp.Shared.DTOs.SeriLog
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using System.Text.Json
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using System.Net.Http.Json

@inject ILogger<ApiCall> _logger;
@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Seri Log Maintenance</PageTitle>


<h3>Start Local: @CurrenTimeLocalStart</h3>
<hr />

@if (Error != null)
{
    <div class="c-error">
        <h3>Error</h3>
        <h5>@Error</h5>
    </div>
}

@if (SeriLogs == null)
{
    <span>
        Loading Seri Logs......
    </span>
}
else
{
    <hr />
    <h3>End Local: @CurrenTimeLocalEnd</h3>
    <SfGrid  ID="Grid" DataSource="@SeriLogs"  @ref="Grid" AllowPaging="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowReordering="true" AllowResizing="true" AllowGrouping="true" AllowExcelExport="true" AllowSelection="false">   
        <GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.FilterBar"></GridFilterSettings>
    <GridPageSettings PageSizes="true"></GridPageSettings>
    <GridSelectionSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple"></GridSelectionSettings>
        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Id) HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.TimeStamp) HeaderText="TimeStamp" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Message) HeaderText="Message" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="500"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Exception) HeaderText="Exception" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.MessageTemplate) HeaderText="MessageTemplate" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="300"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Level) HeaderText="Level" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>

            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Properties) HeaderText="Properties" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.LogEvent) HeaderText="LogEvent" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
        </GridColumns>
    </SfGrid>
}

<style>
    .c-error {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #fff0f4;
        color: #c51244;
    }
</style>

@code {

    SfGrid<SeriLogDTO>? Grid;

    private DateTime CurrenTimeLocalStart { get; set; }

    private DateTime CurrenTimeLocalEnd { get; set; }

    public IList<SeriLogDTO> SeriLogs = null;

    public string Error = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Error = null;
        CurrenTimeLocalStart = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
        try
        {
            var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI");
            var responseResult = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetSeriLogs");

            if (responseResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var contentStream = await responseResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                SeriLogs = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<SeriLogDTO>>(contentStream,
                    new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            }
            else
            {
                // Handle unsuccessful API call
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) // Non success
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
            Error = $"{ex.Message}";
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException ex) // When content type is not valid
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The content type is not supported.");
            Error = $"{ex.Message}";
        }
        catch (JsonException ex) // Invalid JSON
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
            Error = $"{ex.Message}";
        }

        CurrenTimeLocalEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

**Here is my controller code within my Blazor Server project in a Controllers folder:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.Data.Interfaces;

namespace MyApp.Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api")]
    public class MaintenanceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISeriLogRepo seriLogRepo;

        public MaintenanceController(ISeriLogRepo seriLogRepo)
        {
            this.seriLogRepo = seriLogRepo;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetSeriLogs")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var results =  await seriLogRepo.GetSeriLogs();

            return Ok(results); // Returning the serialized results as JSON with 200 OK status
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So it has to do with my web assembly not loading yet. I thought **InteractiveAuto** would hit the server first and then run WASM after the initial call.

So if I hit another page that is set as WASM as well, then it will work on the first click of SeriLog page.

Is there a way to login to the server and then go ahead and download the WASM code even though I thought that was the point of the new .NET 8 functionality?

I think that the 302 redirect is just an offset of the WASM code not downloading yet.

Here are the logs:

```
2023-12-10 21:01:54.028 -06:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 7.4287ms - 200
2023-12-10 21:01:54.028 -06:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 7.8816ms - 200
2023-12-10 21:01:54.042 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44309/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FGetSeriLogs - 200 null text/html; charset=utf-8 18.5648ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.043 -06:00 [INF] Executed endpoint '/maintenance/seri-log (/maintenance/seri-log)'
2023-12-10 21:01:54.043 -06:00 [INF] HTTP GET /maintenance/seri-log responded 200 in 23.4916 ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.045 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44309/maintenance/seri-log - 200 null text/html; charset=utf-8 28.2572ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.243 -06:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44309/maintenance/seri-log - null null
**2023-12-10 21:01:54.246 -06:00 [INF] Executing endpoint '/maintenance/seri-log (/maintenance/seri-log)'
2023-12-10 21:01:54.247 -06:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://localhost:44309/api/GetSeriLogs
2023-12-10 21:01:54.247 -06:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request GET https://localhost:44309/api/GetSeriLogs
2023-12-10 21:01:54.248 -06:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44309/api/GetSeriLogs - null null
2023-12-10 21:01:54.248 -06:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.249 -06:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.249 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44309/api/GetSeriLogs - 302 null null 1.2425ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.250 -06:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44309/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FGetSeriLogs - null null
2023-12-10 21:01:54.250 -06:00 [INF] Executing endpoint '/Account/Login (/Account/Login)'
2023-12-10 21:01:54.251 -06:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.251 -06:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.252 -06:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.252 -06:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:**
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-12-10 21:01:54.253 -06:00 [INF] Executed endpoint '/Account/Login (/Account/Login)'
2023-12-10 21:01:54.253 -06:00 [INF] HTTP GET /Account/Login responded 200 in 3.2765 ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.254 -06:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 6.6562ms - 200
2023-12-10 21:01:54.254 -06:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 7.131ms - 200
2023-12-10 21:01:54.268 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44309/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FGetSeriLogs - 200 null text/html; charset=utf-8 18.2435ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.269 -06:00 [INF] Executed endpoint '/maintenance/seri-log (/maintenance/seri-log)'
2023-12-10 21:01:54.269 -06:00 [INF] HTTP GET /maintenance/seri-log responded 200 in 22.9162 ms
2023-12-10 21:01:54.270 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44309/maintenance/seri-log - 200 null text/html; charset=utf-8 27.2187ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have identified the problem correctly.

To fix it you can:

1. Turn off pre-rendering, so you just get the spinner - `@rendermode @(new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(prerender: false))`.
2. Detect pre-rendering and don't do the API call until the SPA is running on the client.  This answer shows you how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75778169/13065781
3. Add the httpclient services to the server so it can make the API call correctly and get the data.  You can also persist the state (the list you are displaying) from prerender to the full render - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: So if you do the `@rendermode @(new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(prerender: false))` then how do I call the server call without the API call on the Auto - Server part? I placed the file in the server project and it seemed to work with `@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor` but it was always server as true.

Comment: aka Shawn Curtis: I see you answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77525641/net-8-blazor-handling-data-with-auto-global-interactivity is there an example github project you can point me to?

Comment: I found this online that I moved to my repo due to using the old modes: https://github.com/ttaylor29/ExampleNet8DemoTelerik  I found it from here -> https://github.com/jonhilt/Net8DemosTelerik/, but the API call never hits, so I assume it is always running in Server even though I have Auto set?

Comment: @tvb2754 - I'm actually working on a repo and a set of examples as I type.  This is turning out to be soooo confusing for people.  We're all still learning some of the twists.  I'll add a link here shortly and update my answer.

Comment: MrC aka Shaun Curtis: Very confusing! Thank you. I'll be watching out for your updated post!

Comment: Does the project you posted on the other question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652704/16807881, impact this question as well?